# Table cells duplicating when using slide to refresh

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, pull-to-refresh

When using the slide to refresh feature on my RSS table the cells are duplicated showing the most recent update after the the old RSS data. What I mean is that after the refresh the data is added to the table but the old cell aren't removed first. 

My code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.  

        // pull to refresh
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ListViewController.uiRefreshControlAction), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
        self.myTableView.addSubview(refreshControl);


        // set tableview delegate
        self.myTableView.dataSource = self
        self.myTableView.delegate = self
    }

    func uiRefreshControlAction() {
        self.refreshControl.beginRefreshing()
        if let rssURL = NSURL(string: RSS_FEED_URL) {

            // fetch rss content from url
            self.myParser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: rssURL)!

            // set parser delegate
            self.myParser.delegate = self
            self.myParser.shouldResolveExternalEntities = false

            // start parsing
            self.myParser.parse()
        }

    self.myTableView.reloadData()
    self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

Comment: try `tableView.reloadData` after you remove method is called

Comment: @CaffeineShots Sorry I had that already but I forgot to add it to my post.

Comment: where you fill your array which you are giving in the tableview to display the data

Comment: @Pyro Sorry, I'm somewhat confused by your comment.

Comment: in the tableview you are passing some array or value in `numberOfRowsInSection` and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` where do you fill this value to display in the tableview?

Comment: Should I include both of those in the function? Both of those are being passed later in the View Controller: http://pastebin.com/U1b6Eu5t

Comment: try to put  self.myTableView.reloadData() after this self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()

Comment: @CaffeineShots Sorry, but that did not change anything switching those lines around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove all previously fetched rss feed from the rssRecordList array before adding new ones when the tableView is refreshed.

```
func uiRefreshControlAction() {
  refreshControl.beginRefreshing()
  rssRecordList.removeAll()
  ...
}
```

Comment: This fixed the issue. Thanks!